# How do I collect and combine multiple arrays for calculation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am collecting the values for a specific column from a named_scope as follows:

```
a = survey_job.survey_responses.collect(&:base_pay)
```

This gives me a numeric array for example (1,2,3,4,5).  I can then pass this array into various functions I have created to retrieve the mean, median, standard deviation of the number set.  This all works fine however I now need to start combining multiple columns of data to carry out the same types of calculation.

I need to collect the details of perhaps three fields as follows:

```
survey_job.survey_responses.collect(&:base_pay)
survey_job.survey_responses.collect(&:bonus_pay)
survey_job.survey_responses.collect(&:overtime_pay)
```

This will give me 3 arrays.  I then need to combine these into a single array by adding each of the matching values together - i.e. add the first result from each array, the second result from each array and so on so I have an array of the totals.

How do I create a method which will collect all of this data together and how do I call it from the view template?

Really appreciate any help on this one...

Thanks

Simon

Answer (score 2):

```
s = survey_job.survey_responses
pay = s.collect(&:base_pay).zip(s.collect(&:bonus_pay), s.collect(&:overtime_pay))
pay.map{|i| i.compact.inject(&:+) }
```

Do that, but with meaningful variable names and I think it will work.

Define a normal method in app/helpers/_helper.rb and it will work in the view

Edit: now it works if they contain nil or are of different sizes (as long as the longest array is the one on which zip is called.

Comment: Note that this method will not work if your arrays are not all the same size or if they contain nil.

Comment: How do I call this from the view?

Comment: define it as a method in the helper that corresponds to your current controller (located in app/helpers) and it will be available to you in your view.  if you define it in app/helpers/application_helper.rb it will be available in all views.

Comment: I added it in application_helper.rb but I can't work out how to reference it from the view.

I tried  <%= total_cash_pay %> but I guess that's not correct as I get an error: undefined local variable or method `survey_job' for #<ActionView::Base:0x27dc650>

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that will combine an arbitrary number of arrays by taking the sum at each index. It'll allow each array to be of different length, too.

```
def combine(*arrays)
  # Get the length of the largest array, that'll be the number of iterations needed
  maxlen = arrays.map(&:length).max
  out = []

  maxlen.times do |i|
    # Push the sum of all array elements at a given index to the result array
    out.push( arrays.map{|a| a[i]}.inject(0) { |memo, value| memo += value.to_i } )
  end

  out
end
```

Then, in the controller, you could do

```
base_pay = survey_job.survey_responses.collect(&:base_pay)
bonus_pay = survey_job.survey_responses.collect(&:bonus_pay)
overtime_pay = survey_job.survey_responses.collect(&:overtime_pay)

@total_pay = combine(base_pay, bonus_pay, overtime_pay)
```

And then refer to `@total_pay` as needed in your view.

Comment: I'm doing this calculation inside the main loop for the report.  I loop through survey_jobs and need to do this set of calculations for each survey_job in the collection.  If I post the controller code I get an error:

    NameError in Admin/surveysController#show
    undefined local variable or method `survey_job' for   #<SurveysController:0x2230ad0>

Am I misunderstanding how I should apply this code in the controller?